# Get an event's details from Calendar.app

Tags: python, macos, calendar, applescript

How can I get information about a days' events?

E.g. get all the events happening today, their times, invitees, etc.

The end goal is to interface this with a flashlight utility, so I'm gonna wrap the applescript query in a python `subprocess` and use the results in that python program.

Comment: Have you tried using a database with two tables (one with the dates and one with events)?

Comment: @Ronikos how do I get the events from calendar?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You want to use applescript to get data from Calendar.app and then pass that to python?

Comment: @Ronikos yeah, exactly, unless it is possible for python to just get the data from the calendar itself

Comment: Perhaps look into http://eventable.github.io/vobject/

Answer (score 1):

The script bellow gets all events from a date which start time is from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59 for the selected date :

```
property my_calendar : "Calendar"

set my_date to (current date) -- or any other date you want

copy my_date to Start_Date
set time of Start_Date to 0
copy my_date to End_Date
set time of End_Date to 86399 -- 23:59:59 in seconds

tell application "Calendar"
tell calendar my_calendar
    -- read all events betwen start and end dates
    set my_List to (every event whose (start date is greater than or equal to Start_Date) and (start date is less than or equal to End_Date))

    repeat with myEvent in my_List -- loop through each event
        --do something
        log (start date of myEvent) as string
    end repeat
end tell --Calendar
end tell -- application
```

Comment: What is the API for interacting with `myEvent`? If I were running this script from a python script, how could I pass the details of each `myEvent` back to the python caller?

Comment: I'm not expert in Python, sorry. if you end your Applescript with something like 'return xxx', usually it gives back xxx to the caller of the script; I am using this with Terminal / shell commands. It may be similar with Python ?